# How to show extremal region of text in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, text

I have code from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp). It's reference from Neumann L., Matas J.: Real-Time Scene Text Localization and Recognition, CVPR 2012.

Result is rectan of text region, but I need the output like [this](http://www.mx7.com/view2/ytLzmc8Li8Uosm9S) for analysis.

How to show extremal regions of text in this code? I try to show image by `imshow("",regions);`, but it does not work.

in this code

```html
vector< vector<Vec2i> > region_groups;
vector<Rect> groups_boxes;
    erGrouping(src, channels, regions, region_groups, groups_boxes, ERGROUPING_ORIENTATION_HORIZ);
```

sorry for my mistake . I'm not strong langues too!!

I would like to draw region_groups into the white picture

Comment: this is result of code above http://www.mx7.com/view2/ytLAyhHiym8FCSzN

and tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html#

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV 3.0.0 MSER Binary Mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515084/opencv-3-0-0-mser-binary-mask)

Comment: Thx u @Miki it's very useful